# Unnest one column from a nested list of tibbles?

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

From a dataframe I have been adding and manipulating data till I get sthg like this

```
# A tibble: 165 × 4
# Groups:   gen [55]
   grup_int gen     RQ_avg_group data              
   <fct>    <chr>          <dbl> <list>            
 1 3        ppara           1.59 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 2 3        ppard           1.43 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 3 3        pparg           1.39 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 4 3        nr1h3           1.31 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 5 3        nr1h2           1.48 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 6 3        rxra            1.44 <tibble [51 × 25]>
```

Inside the nested list there is a column named RQ (for sure), what if I want just to unnest or pluck this column, but keeping the rest nested?

```
# This simple code is not working
genes_plot3 %>% unnest(RQ)



Error in `unnest()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `RQ` doesn't exist.


genes_plot3 %>% unnest(.$data [["RQ"]])

# A tibble: 165 × 4
# Groups:   gen [55]
   grup_int gen     RQ_avg_group data              
   <fct>    <chr>          <dbl> <list>            
 1 3        ppara           1.59 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 2 3        ppard           1.43 <tibble [51 × 25]>
 3 3        pparg           1.39 <tibble [51 × 25]>
```

Is there any simple way avoiding sthg like(which by the way is not working either)

```
genes_plot3 %>% dplyr::mutate(tmp = list(dplyr::select(data, RQ))) %>% unnest(tmp)
```

Thanks in advance!

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(grup_int = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    RQ = c(1.143, 0.909, 1.345, 1.942, 0.977, 1.046, 1.334, 0.853, 
    1.007, 1.089), data = list(structure(list(id = c(50203029, 
    50203029), sample_name = structure(c("A2537700029000006001", 
    "A2537700029000006001"), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure(c("OCW08_2022_04_26_132458.eds", 
        "OCW08_2022_04_26_132458.eds"), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = c(0, 0), edad0 = c(57, 57), peso1 = c(96.9, 96.9
        ), imc1 = c(33.14, 33.14), cintura1 = c(110, 110), cadera1 = c(NA_real_, 
        NA_real_), peso3 = c(94.8, 94.8), imc3 = c(32.42, 32.42
        ), cintura3 = c(112, 112), cadera3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_
        ), endogenous_ct_01 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), endogenous_ct_03 = c(11.356, 
        11.356), d_peso = c(-2.1, -2.1), d_cintura = c(2, 2), 
        d_cadera = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), d_imc = c(-0.72, -0.72
        ), gen = c("cd36", "cd36"), time = c(3, 3), Ct = c(15.581, 
        15.581), dCt = c(4.225, 4.225), ddCt = c(-0.193, -0.193
        ), RQ_avg = c(1.372, 1.372)), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "cd36", .rows = structure(list(1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 50508026, sample_name = structure("A2541700026000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 1, edad0 = 74, peso1 = 60.6, imc1 = 27.3, cintura1 = 98, 
        cadera1 = 100, peso3 = 62.1, imc3 = 27.97, cintura3 = 104, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 12.126, 
        d_peso = 1.5, d_cintura = 6, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = 0.67, 
        gen = "ido", time = 3, Ct = 20.791, dCt = 8.665, ddCt = 0.138, 
        RQ_avg = 1.362), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "ido", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 140102095, sample_name = structure("A2591900095000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW08_2022_04_26_132458.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 1, edad0 = 61, peso1 = 87, imc1 = 34.41, cintura1 = 109, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 86.3, imc3 = 34.14, cintura3 = 106, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 11.319, 
        d_peso = -0.7, d_cintura = -3, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -0.27, 
        gen = "rxra", time = 3, Ct = 13.567, dCt = 2.248, ddCt = -0.428, 
        RQ_avg = 1.399), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "rxra", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = c(120715034, 120715034), sample_name = structure(c("A2582200034000006001", 
        "A2582200034000006001"), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure(c("OCW11_2022_04_26_132517.eds", 
        "OCW11_2022_04_26_132517.eds"), label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = c(0, 0), edad0 = c(68, 68), peso1 = c(95.5, 95.5
        ), imc1 = c(33.04, 33.04), cintura1 = c(120, 120), cadera1 = c(NA_real_, 
        NA_real_), peso3 = c(100, 100), imc3 = c(34.6, 34.6), 
        cintura3 = c(123, 123), cadera3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_
        ), endogenous_ct_01 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), endogenous_ct_03 = c(13.313, 
        13.313), d_peso = c(4.5, 4.5), d_cintura = c(3, 3), d_cadera = c(NA_real_, 
        NA_real_), d_imc = c(1.56, 1.56), gen = c("ldlr", "ldlr"
        ), time = c(3, 3), Ct = c(19.702, 19.702), dCt = c(6.389, 
        6.389), ddCt = c(-0.957, -0.957), RQ_avg = c(1.525, 1.525
        )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(gen = "ldlr", 
        .rows = structure(list(1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 140102089, sample_name = structure("A2591900089000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 0, edad0 = 62, peso1 = 70, imc1 = 28.4, cintura1 = 100, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 69.7, imc3 = 28.28, cintura3 = 94, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 11.416, 
        d_peso = -0.3, d_cintura = -6, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -0.12, 
        gen = "nlrp3", time = 3, Ct = 16.548, dCt = 5.132, ddCt = 0.034, 
        RQ_avg = 1.337), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "nlrp3", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 140103023, sample_name = structure("A2592000023000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 0, edad0 = 68, peso1 = 81.5, imc1 = 29.94, cintura1 = 107, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 83, imc3 = 30.49, cintura3 = 111, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 12.532, 
        d_peso = 1.5, d_cintura = 4, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = 0.55, 
        gen = "cyp27a1", time = 3, Ct = 17.295, dCt = 4.763, 
        ddCt = -0.065, RQ_avg = 1.374), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "cyp27a1", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 50203006, sample_name = structure("A2537700006000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW07_2022_04_26_110614.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 1, edad0 = 60, peso1 = 64.2, imc1 = 27.79, cintura1 = 93, 
        cadera1 = 93, peso3 = 63.2, imc3 = 27.35, cintura3 = 92, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 11.125, 
        d_peso = -1, d_cintura = -1, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -0.44, 
        gen = "lrp1", time = 3, Ct = 17.336, dCt = 6.211, ddCt = -0.415, 
        RQ_avg = 1.998), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "lrp1", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 140102092, sample_name = structure("A2591900092000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW09_2022_04_26_132510.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 0, edad0 = 71, peso1 = 90.1, imc1 = 32.7, cintura1 = 110, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 88.1, imc3 = 31.97, cintura3 = 108, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 11.836, 
        d_peso = -2, d_cintura = -2, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -0.73, 
        gen = "cdkn2a", time = 3, Ct = 21.576, dCt = 9.74, ddCt = 0.229, 
        RQ_avg = 1.307), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "cdkn2a", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 110606061, sample_name = structure("A2574500061000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW11_2022_04_26_132517.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 0, edad0 = 64, peso1 = 76.8, imc1 = 27.87, cintura1 = 94, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 76.1, imc3 = 27.62, cintura3 = 94, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 12.464, 
        d_peso = -0.7, d_cintura = 0, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -0.25, 
        gen = "cd86", time = 3, Ct = 18.322, dCt = 5.858, ddCt = -0.011, 
        RQ_avg = 1.244), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "cd86", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)), structure(list(
        id = 60901031, sample_name = structure("A2552500031000006001", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A20", display_width = 20L), 
        experiment_name = structure("OCW10_2022_04_26_132513.eds", label = "lab_exp_genica:", format.spss = "A27", display_width = 27L), 
        sexo = 1, edad0 = 69, peso1 = 82.5, imc1 = 35.24, cintura1 = 106, 
        cadera1 = NA_real_, peso3 = 75, imc3 = 32.04, cintura3 = 102, 
        cadera3 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_01 = NA_real_, endogenous_ct_03 = 12.817, 
        d_peso = -7.5, d_cintura = -4, d_cadera = NA_real_, d_imc = -3.2, 
        gen = "abca1", time = 3, Ct = 17.857, dCt = 5.04, ddCt = -0.123, 
        RQ_avg = 1.665), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        gen = "abca1", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE)))), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the data. There is no RQ variable in the data-column (but one that isn't nested), however there is a `RQ_avg` that we can extract and unnest: `df1 |> mutate(RQ_avg = map(data, ~ select(., RQ_avg))) |> unnest(RQ_avg)`. (I've ignored the error about the grouping variable as I guess that's not a problem on the real data, but it might challenge you at some point). As the rows in the nested tibbble are identical in the provided data, you'll create unnest-duplicates: We could do: `mutate(RQ_avg = map(data, ~ distinct(select(., RQ_avg))))`, but you might want to store it once only.

Comment: I don't know why in df1 is not RQ, but sure in my database it was. Your syntax is workin but I need to specify the package:
df1 |> dplyr::mutate(RQ_avg = map(data, ~ dplyr::select(., RQ_avg))) |> unnest(RQ_avg)
 I don't know why by default there are several functions as select and mutate, that RStudio picks certain package with characteristics that not always work. Thanks!

Comment: You’re probably having a package conflict with dplyr. Happy it is working :-)